# Difference between value and binding tag for UIComponents in JSF

Tags: jsf, uicomponents

I am learning JSF and am confused in these two attributes. What difference will it make if I will use:

`<h:inputText value="#{myBean.myProperty}/>"`

rather than using:

`<h:inputText binding="#{myBean.myProperty}/>"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the tag library API:

1. **value**: javax.el.ValueExpression (**must evaluate to
   java.lang.Object**). The current value of this component.
2. **binding**: javax.el.ValueExpression (**must evaluate to
   javax.faces.component.UIComponent**). The ValueExpression linking
   this component to a property in a backing bean

Comment: Even when we use the Value, we can insert value in it. Then what specifically is the meaning of `Linking a backing bean property`? Can't we use the `Value` expression to do the same?

Comment: value is bound to the Object in the backing bean that holds the value of the input text, binding is bound to the actual input text component. You can get the value from this uicomponent object but you can also get a lot more, you can also change the component attributes if you like in your backing bean